# PHP using Laravel 4 and Carbon will not print out a DateTime field from my Database

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a PHP application with Laravel 4.

I am getting errors when I try to print out a DateTime record from the Database though.

`{{ $user->created_at }}`

Gives me this error

> InvalidArgumentException
>     Trailing data
>     open: E:\Server\htdocs\projects\timeclock\www\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php

Very frustrating!

An example value from that Database field is: `2013-08-31 20:50:25`.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the milisecond data on the time stamp, you need to use:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', $value)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) it:

```
{{ $user->created_at->format('h:i:s') }}
```

[The PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters) has a list of all the codes available to use as a format.

Comment: Ahh this doesn't resolve my error though.  What is more strange is it works fine on another  DateTime field, just this 1 field is not playing nice even thought it looks the same just different name then the other one

Comment: Only solution I could find so far was to rename my table column to a new name and now it works.

Comment: Created_at and updated_at are column names of Laravel's 'timestamps' functionality - eloquent ORM treats them specially. Are you not using that functionality specifically?

Comment: @fideloper - What do you mean by "eloquent ORM treats them specially"? AFAIK, if you don't create your own `getDates` method, Eloquent will automatically convert those columns to instances of Carbon, in which case `->format()` should work. Am I missing something?

Comment: I wasn't uses the built in functionality but instead created my own created_at column in the DB and set it as a Datetime instead of the timestamp.  Anyways I have renamed it now so there is no confusion

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue.

And I found that this is caused by my timestamp data in database.

2013-12-13 22:40:50.561709  <- this one will cause the issue.

2013-12-13 22:40:50         <- this one will not.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp value with millisecond causes this issue.

Column which is converted to Carbon object can not have millisecond timestamp.(default: created_at, updated_at).
http://readouble.com/laravel/4/2/0/en/eloquent.html#date-mutators

If Carbon Object is not necessary, you can disallow auto-converting.

```
class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

    public function getDates()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

But it also make Carbon methods(ex:->format()) unavailable. You have to format timestamps in other way.